# irregular Python/Scrapy scraping behaviour: Status 200 but data not always returned

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a Python Scrapy spider to scrape 60,000 pages from a website. Each of the items extracted work greats, and when scraping approximately 4000 pages, I have no issues, I get a 200 status from each page and all data required is extracted.

However when I start to scrape 8000 pages upwards, I am sometimes able to scrape all the data with 200 status codes, but on other occasions I get very few items returned. The output still displays all 8000 urls and a 200 status code for each, but very few associated items extracted.

I notice that if the crawler has successfully scraped all 8000 pages, and is then run almost immediately again, this behaviour occurs. Its the same behaviour seen when trying to scrape all 60,000 pages.

I have the following enabled within the settings.py file:

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

My code is as follows:

```
import scrapy
import re
import sqlite3
import time
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class UserItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
    registered = scrapy.Field()

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "website"
    allowed_domains = ['source_website']
    start_urls = ['http://source_website/page1',
                  'http://source_website/page2',
                  'http://source_website/page3',
                  'http://source_website/page4',
                  'http://source_website/page5',]


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = scrapy.Selector(response)
        all_links = hxs.xpath('*//a/@href').extract()
        for link in all_links:
            yield scrapy.http.Request(url=response.urljoin(link), callback=self.ParseContents)

    def ParseContents(self, response):
        item = UserItem()

        item['url'] = response.url
        item['status'] = response.status

        data = (response.xpath('//html//text()').extract())
        data = iter(data)
        for object in data:
            if "Registered" in object:
                item['registered'] = (next(data))

        yield item
```

Successful scrape log:

```
2018-03-10 17:49:09 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 2489755,
 'downloader/request_count': 7524,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 7524,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 19301544,
 'downloader/response_count': 7524,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 7520,
 'downloader/response_status_count/302': 4,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 45,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 17, 49, 9, 119209),
 'item_scraped_count': 7517,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 15046,
 'log_count/INFO': 14,
 'memusage/max': 123379712,
 'memusage/startup': 49389568,
 'offsite/domains': 2,
 'offsite/filtered': 4,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 7520,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 7524,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 7524,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 7524,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 7524,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 10, 17, 42, 25, 211537)}
2018-03-10 17:49:09 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Ironically at the time of updating this, I'm unable to produce an unsuccessful scrape log as the spider scrapes the 8000 odd pages at the moment.

Could this the website managing the volume of traffic its receiving, therefore the behaviour of the spider is sporadic?

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you some code? control your item setting, pre post processors, ecc...

Comment: Hi Lore, I've updated my original post to hopefully provide some additional information.